# How to pass value in PDO prepare

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO articles (author, subject, text, date, 
special) VALUES (:author, :subject, :text, :date, :special)');
```

How should it look like when i need to add "special" value to database but "date is automatic and i dont need it in prepare statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just omit it

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO articles (author, subject, text,  
special) VALUES (:author, :subject, :text, :special)');
```

That's SQL syntax that has nothing to do with PDO and prepared statements.

If you don't want to prepare some value - just don't prepare it. That's all

Answer (score 1):

Make Your statement by omitting date

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO articles (author, subject, text,  
special) VALUES (:author, :subject, :text, :special)');
```

AND in database make date with type TIMESTAMP and default value = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".

Answer (score 0):

An other option is to make `date` with type TIMESTAMP and default value = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".

Consequently the database will do the work itself.